# Put base64 decoded image data into cv::Mat in opencv: Chrome native messaging

Tags: opencv, base64, chrome-native-messaging

How to decode **base64** string and put it into Mat variable. Accually i can decode it using c++ but after that i don't know how to pass it to Mat.
I tried searching but didn't find any clear pointed solution(so don't mark as duplicate since there are no solution to this exact question available).

I'm using chrome native messaging and i need to load image data into `cv::Mat` received through the `STDIN`.

On client-side image is encoded using javascript dataURL.

P.S:- Please don't suggest PNACL for this since it does not serve what i exactly need.

Comment: base64_decode() -> [imdecode()](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga26a67788faa58ade337f8d28ba0eb19e)-> cv::Mat

Comment: But how i pass it to imdecode(). Guess i can't just pass string to the function.

Comment: can't you put it into a vector<uchar> ?